# Having trouble with my css formatting

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my CSS styling. The text on my submit button is not displaying properly. Below is a picture as well as the code that I am using.Thank you for your help.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/FKL9s7U.jpg?1]

```
<style>
    input[type=submit] { float: left; width: 160px; height:25px; }
    input {
       -moz-border-radius:40px;
       -webkit-border-radius:40px;
       border-radius:40px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Please post your html as well.

Comment: Your CSS looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/YeEzj/. Please provide more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to adjust the `line-height` of the text for the search button. Hard to know exactly where this would need to be without seeing the rest of the relevant code.

Comment: Could also be a `padding` issue on that button.  Maybe try setting `padding-top: 0;` and see where that lands you?

Comment: Yeah it could also be a padding issue. Again hard for us to know exactly with such a small code snippet.